how to fetch all users showing whether I am following them or not?
So, I'm making a following system like Instagram using Postgresql in Supabase.
This is my follows table:
CREATE TABLE follows {
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  following_user_id UUID,
  followed_user_id UUID,
  CONSTRAINT pk_follow PRIMARY KEY (following_user_id, followed_user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (following_user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (followed_user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
}

Let me explain some codes here:
following_user_id is someone's id that the user follows.
followed_user_id is that user's id.
So, suppose there is a user A that follows user B.
In the data structure of user A, follwed_user_id is userA's id and following_user_id is user B's id since user A follows them.
But the problem is, how to show whether a user is following someone when fetching all users?
I'm thinking to add a boolean isFollowing column.
So I did some search and wrote a query:
const getUsersFollowMeInFormat = `
SELECT 
    f.followed_user_id AS userid,
    u.username,
    u.profile_img,
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM follows
        WHERE followed_user_id = $1 AND following_user_id = f.followed_user_id
    ) AS isfollowing
FROM follows f
JOIN users u ON f.followed_user_id = u.id
WHERE following_user_id = $1;
`;

This query returns all user data with their username, profile, and following info.
It seems work, but how can I achieve this in Supabase?

You can write that SQL query in a Postgres function and then call it via the .rpc call from the Supabase SDK. Your function would look something like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_users_follow_me (
  user_id uuid
) RETURNS TABLE(userId uuid, username text, profile_img text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$function$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT 
        f.followed_user_id AS userid,
        u.username,
        u.profile_img,
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM follows
            WHERE followed_user_id = $1 AND following_user_id = f.followed_user_id
        ) AS isfollowing
    FROM follows f
    JOIN users u ON f.followed_user_id = u.id
    WHERE following_user_id = $1;
  END;
$function$;

And then you can call it with the Supabase Javascript SDK like:
await supabase.rpc('get_users_follow_me', { user_id: 'your_user_id_here' })

Note this is not tested and is just an example code to guide you into achieving what you are after.

Thanks, this totally makes sense. But, is this how every social media application normally does or the best solution for user following system?
